# Undefined control sequence \WHILE

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e, algorithmicx, algorithmic

I get a Undefined control sequence \WHILE error in my latex code.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{algorithm} 
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}
$ \bar{w} \leftarrow  w.$

$S = \{u \in V : w(u) = 0 \}$.
$ \WHILE{S is not a hitting set for C} do
  \mathcal{M} $  a collection of cycles returned by a violation oracle Violation(G, C, S).
$c_{ \mathcal{M} (u) } \leftarrow |{M _ M : u _ M}|, for all u _ V $.
 $ \alpha 
\leftarrow min_ {u \in V \backslash S} | w(u) /
c_{M (u) } $
$\bar{
w(u) } \leftarrow  w(u) - \alpha cM (u),$ for all u in V.
$ S \leftarrow \{u _ V : w(u) = 0 \}. 
\ENDWHILE $
%end
return a minimal hitting set $ H \subset S $ of $\mathcal{C}$.
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Also I'm a bit confused about the various algorithms packages and which can be used together

Comment: First of, the while should not be n math mode and it should be While not WHILE. See the manual for reference

Comment: but capital \While appears in https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Algorithms#An_example_from_the_manual
also I've tried doing it not in mathmode still doesn't work

Comment: I guess you're correct, but do take the example from that page and adapt it, basically most of what you are doing here is wrong, a lot of stuff that should not be in math mode and a lot of stuff that should be in math mode. Also please make this example complete, there is no preamble, when people have to guess code in order to help, they are much less likely to bother helping

Comment: If you look at the wiki every line starts with a statement, an algorithm is actually a sort of list, thus the very first line you use is wrong as it is not a statement. Otherwise look in the manual linked to from the wiki

Comment: sorry I don't understand your comment daleif  what is wrong with the first line?
also I've deleted the first line and it still doesn't work

Comment: You are writing some math, that is not allowed in this setup. It should be some like `\STATE `, `\IF` or what ever, again compare with the example in the wiki.

Comment: okay it seems that \usepackage{algorithmicx}  was most of the problem it should be \usepackage{algorithmic}?  although I still get a  somethings wrong error

Comment: Basically the problem is two fold: (1) you are not using the correct syntax for the `algorithmicx` it belongs to the `algorithmic` package (2) each line need to be a statement. Swtiching to `algorithmic` you'll get a much more appropriate error message. This just shows why one should always post full examples, it is hard to understand which packages are used for what from that WIKI page.

Answer (score 3):

This example works (not sure if I formatted it correctly).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}
  \STATE $ \bar{w} \leftarrow  w.$
  \STATE $S = \{u \in V : w(u) = 0 \}$.
  \WHILE{$S$ is not a hitting set for $C$} 
  \STATE $\mathcal{M} $  a collection of cycles returned by a violation oracle Violation(G, C, S).
  \STATE $c_{ \mathcal{M} (u) } \leftarrow |{M _ M : u _ M}|, for all u _ V $.
  \STATE $ \alpha \leftarrow min_ {u \in V \backslash S} | w(u) / c_{M (u) } $
  \STATE $\bar{ w(u) } \leftarrow  w(u) - \alpha cM (u),$ for all u in V.
  \STATE $ S \leftarrow \{u _ V : w(u) = 0 \}$. 
\ENDWHILE 
\RETURN a minimal hitting set $ H \subset S $ of $\mathcal{C}$.
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

The WIKI page you refer to is rather hard to read, it is not clear which pseudocode package is used where, and they do not use the same syntax (that's why I reacted on `\WHILE` and thought is was spelled differently (not all upper case). The syntax the same use is from `algorithmic` not why one you're trying to use.

Comment: @HaoS Problem solved?